# Jquery $('.class').live('click',...) - not finding multiple gridview columns with same class name

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a .aspx page (vb.net back-end) that I am adding jQuery functions to to decrease postbacks.  the page has around a dozen gridviews that are bound to data and have 5 templated field that are not (1 check box and 4 radio buttons per row).

What I am trying to accomplish is jquery functionality that handles changes to the template columns.  I have jquery working perfectly, but only if there is one gridview that I am working with.  As I stated previously, the page has ~12 gridviews total, all formatted the same and thus need jquery to operate the same. (one option is to replicate what I have 12 times :(...)

I thought that if I could get this to work for two of the twelve, then I'd be set, but I can't figure it out.  I'm very new to jquery and what i do have working is in thanks to these and other message boards.  After much searching, using '.class' seems to be the answer to what i am wanting to accomplish, but it is not working as I'd expect.

I've taken the html and and what jquery I am trying to get to work and loaded it here to [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/jkmurphy1/68Mpy/)

Can someone take a look and help me get the 'alert' for my '.class' to work?  If I get this going, I think I may be able to handle the rest of the jquery I will need.

The first two work as expected.  The last only works for the first item with the class 'rbAllNA':

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(rbAllNA1).live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
$(rbAllNA2).live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});

$(".rbAllNA").live('click', function() {
    alert("call from class");
});
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jkmurphy1/68Mpy/1/ for the full scenario.

Comment: `live` has been deprecated. Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: thanks.  I have updated that in my code and will us .on instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with you code was

In the **first table** - `class="rbAllNA"`

In the **second table** - `class="rbAllNa"`  **<--** `a should have been uppercase`

Your selector is `$(".rbAllNA")`

**HTML attributes are case sensitive** .. So the later won't work..

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/68Mpy/2/)**

`.live()` has been deprecated as of `1.7.0` .. Attach events using `.on()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The first input element has class 'rbAllNA', live statement works. The second has 'rbAllNa' (i.e. with lowercase a as last letter). Change it to uppercase 'A', and it works in you jsfiddle sample